# "Your delete vote has been recorded" message for undelete vote

Tags: bug, voting, localization, vote-to-undelete

When I have voted for undeletion, the system showed me message about deletion.

> [image]

And looks like it isn't the localization problem, 'cause in traducir everything is fine: https://ru.traducir.win/filters?translationRegex=%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20

Looks like the system shows incorrect message for undeletion vote.

Discussion on SOru:
["Ваш голос за удаление учтён" при голосовании за восстановление](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8456/15479)